# Importing XML file in ArcGIS failed

Tags: arcgis-10.0, import, xml, geodatabase-xml

I have created a model in Enterprise Architect (in ArcGIS technology). Inside I have several point, polygon, line feature classes and a couple of domains which correspond to them.

From the level of EA I export my model to ArcGIS XML Workspace. Then when I try to import it in ArcGIS 10 I get an error as below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [ArcGIS Diagrammer](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geodatabase/details?entryID=F12ADF8F-1422-2418-34B2-C276C6BCCF98)?

Comment: No, I am using only Enterprise Architect. But as far as i know it is compatible with ArcGIS 10, so it should be working.
Is it any possibility to import Enterprise Architect file (.eap) to ArcGIS Diagrammer? Then i would try it.

Comment: It can open ESRI XML Workspace documents but I think that's it.

Comment: Ok I have tried your clue.
After i load the xml to ArcGIS Diagrammer (generated in Enterprise Architect) the schema looks nice and correct. 

But after exporting it to .xml file (from level of ArcGIS Diagrammer) and then loading it to ArcGIS a get a following error:
http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/Clipboard_rrwnewr.jpg/

Comment: That is saying that you already have the domain values in your existing db. you would need to do a schema comparison, in the replication tools, then create the delta xml, and load that.

Comment: Have you tried loading it into a new, empty file geodatabase?

Comment: Yes, I tried to load it into new empty personal&file geodatabase.

Comment: To get more help consider:
- opening xml in editor that shows line numbers (notepad++, notepad2) and inspecting what is there;
- translating error message from Polish to English. [Edit] - Should be converted to comment. (I don't know how to do it.)

Comment: Please post line 85792 (and maybe a few surrounding lines) from your file.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Here you have the last few lines http://ifotos.pl/zobacz/Clipboard_rrawssa.jpg/

Comment: I put the last lines of code in post avove. Translating this polish words in this error is just: unspecified error

Comment: Try to double-click your file. It has .xml extension, right? See what IE will tell you.I doubt in XML validity, it's XML parsing error, as I understood.

Comment: Yes, it is .xml extension as I mentioned before and yes, it is parse error as it is shown at the main post (screen).

Comment: If I understand correctly you were using Enterprise Architect (EA) from sparxsystems to build your UML model. EA saves its UML as XML and that XML is not valid XML. No there is not esri yet, there are possibly bugs from sparxsystems. Check their Current Release, Version 9.2, Build 922, 19-January-2012. Maybe it works better with 'legacy geospatial databases' (sniff).