# ArcGIS XML Import Failed - how to find out why it failed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, geodatabase-xml

I am creating an ESRi XML Workspace document in some of my own C# code. The XML doc that is produced validates against the GdbExchange.xsd schema provided by ESRI. However, when I use ArcCatalog to import the XML document into a newly created Personal Geodatabase (.mdb) I get the following error:

```
Import xml data failed
FDO error: -2147186428 [XML parse error: Unspecified error
 [Line: 415, column: 23].]
```

The line and column indicated above are:

```
    ...
    </DatasetDefinitions>
    <Metadata xsi:type="esri:XmlPropertySet">
        <XmlDoc />
    </Metadata>
</WorkspaceDefinition> <!-- THIS LINE -->
<WorkspaceData xsi:type="esri:WorkspaceData">
    <DatasetData xsi:type="esri:TableData">
        <DatasetName>PointInspections</DatasetName>
        ...
```

(Column 23 is after the closing angle bracket, ">", an the line marked "< !-- THIS LINE -->")

Given that the XML document is valid, how can I get more useful information from ArcGIS?

(There is a somewhat similar question asked here: [Importing XML file in ArcGIS failed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19739/importing-xml-file-in-arcgis-failed), but that didn't have a resolution that worked for me...)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you edited the XML from a program like Notepad++.

I have had an experience in the past where the XML was OK in all respects, but because I had edited it using Notepad++, it was not readable.

Try creating another (fresh) copy of the XML using Visual Studio XML editor or Windows notepad.

Comment: Howdy @ujjwalesri, thanks for your answer. Yep, I have indeed examined the generated file using Notepad++ (and have validated it using Notepad++'s XML Tools), and it is fine. (I can provide a copy of the file, if anyone wants to double check my generated file...)

Comment: I think I misunderstood @ujjwalesri's answer: maybe they are saying I **shouldn't** use Notepad++ to edit the XML file. Not convinced that is the problem, but I have re-generated my XML file (from my custom written C# application), and verified that the file validates against the XSD, and that the line endings are correct.

Comment: Are you simply parsing this XML...or deserializing it?